# What is an intuitive explanation for the Importance Weighted Autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoder, generative-models

I have been reading a paper by [Burda et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00519). on Importance Weighted Autoencoders(IWAE) but I can't quite grasp what they mean by sampling the terms **h**1...**h**k. Do they mean you have separate models from which you sample and then average over?

Comment: post something more from the paper explaining what are those terms